# Prove the Dual-Converse Relationship

Tags: logic, meta-math

Using a Hilbert-type system, given
 $ E \sim F ,E' \sim F', E \implies F $
 prove $ F' \implies E' $ 
where a propositional formula A' is obtained by interchanging & and V in A.
My answer is proving $ E' \implies F' $
and then use two replacements for both formulas.
Would that suffice?

$ \sim $ is being used for equivalence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is relative to S.C.Kleene's *Introduction to Metamathematics*, page 122, it seems to me that you have slightly "altered" the sense of the exercise.

At page 122 it is proved the :

> **Corollary** : if $E$ and $F$ are two propositional formulae built up from propositional letters $P_i$ and their *negations* $\lnot P_i$ with the only connectives : $\lor$ and $\land$ and we define as $E'$ and $F'$ the formulae obtained respectively from $E$ and $F$ applying the following transformation : interchange $\land$ and $\lor$ and each proposition letter $P_i$ with its negation, we have that :
>
> > if $\vdash E \sim F$, then $\vdash E' \sim F'$ [where $\sim$ stay for the *equivalece*, i.e. the *bi-conditional* : $A \sim B$ **iff** $(A \supset B) \land (B \supset A)$].

Then, **Corallary** page 124 ask to reexamine the previous proof in order to verify that :

> > if $\vdash E \supset F$, then $\vdash F' \supset E'$.

In order to prove it, we have to adapt the proof given at page 122, based on previous results :

- *First step* : assume $\vdash E \supset F$ and substitute each proposition letter $P_i$ with its negation : $\lnot P_i$; applying the substitution rule [**Th.3**, page 109] we get : $\vdash E^* \supset F^*$;
- *Second step* : apply the replacement property of equivalence [**Th.6** and **Coroll**, page 117] using double negation to get $\vdash E^{*1} \supset F^{*1}$;

see Kleene, last line of page 122 : "the effect of these two operations is to interchange the proposition letters with their negations";

- *Third step* : intead of $*30$, we need here $*12$ : $A \supset B \vdash \lnot B \supset \lnot A$, to get : $\vdash \lnot F^{*1} \supset \lnot E^{*1}$;
- *Finally*, apply the preliminary result for duality [**Th.8**, page 121] to "move inside" the leading negation signs [applying *De Morgan's laws*] to get : $\vdash \lnot F^{*2} \supset \lnot E^{*2}$, which is : $\vdash F' \supset E'$;

see Kleene, second line page 123 : "these last two steps effect the interchange of $\land$ with $\lor$, and interchange the proposition letters with their negations a second time to restore them to their original condition".